# Will a t-test for the change in repeated lab results be much different than a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, pre-post-comparison

I have a dataset of 200 patients with lab results at time a given year and the previous year. The hypothesis is that in patients with a high-risk disease (group A) the change in the lab result will be steeper than in the low-risk (group B). For example we expect Hgb to drop by an average of 2g/l/year in group A and by 0.5 g/L/year in group B.

For simplicity, I calculated the change in lab results and just ran a simple t-test. I was wondering - should I expect a considerably different result if I run the test on result at the two timepoints as repeated measures using `lme`?

Similarly, should I to expect considerably different results with `coxph` using the change vs. `coxme` with the repeated measurements?

If I should use a mixed model, would the following be correct?

```
lmer(group ~ time * hgb + (time | subjects), data=data)
```